# Running apache with user subdirectories

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

What shall I do if I want to make apache to automatically create ~username subdirectories for each account? I tried to google it but I don't know how to call this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, what you're looking for is **mod_userdir**.

Enabling it depends on the distribution you're using.

For **CentOS**
Open /etc/httpd/httpd.conf - search for and change:

```
UserDir disable
```

To:

```
UserDir enable
```

Or, for **Ubuntu/Debian**:

```
a2enmod userdir
```

Afterwards you'll need to restart your webserver, i.e.

```
service httpd restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

You are also able to configure what directory is used for userdir (default public_html) by specifying **UserDir [name of dir]** instead of **UserDir enable**

Comment: I just reread your question - this doesn't CREATE the directories, just configures Apache to use them. If you want to create the physical  directories you need to either manually do it or script it. You'll need to create a public_html directory in each users home. But I think my original answer is what you wanted anyway!